# How do I return dynamic TXT records based on wildcard subdomains?

Tags: node.js, networking, dns

For example, I'd want foo.example.com to return the following TXT record

```
foo:bar
```

This might be a language agnostic question meaning that you'd have to resolve dns lookups on your server, but I'm curious as to how I would tackle this challenge using node.js. The bar part of the TXT record would be returned from a database; not sure if that throws a wrench in the whole ordeal.

Comment: You need to find a nameserver that allows you to plug any program to dynamically reply to queries. bind has dynamic backends, powerdns has a lua backend, and there are other examples. It is not really a simple case. Or you need to develop a full nameserver in your programming language, but this is not easy as well, if you want to fully conform to the DNS protocol (except if you can rely on good DNS libraries). Maybe explain more your use case with TXT records? And at that stage, without code, your question is probably more ontopic for [softwarerecs.se] or [softwareengineering.se] than here.

Comment: My use case would be using OpenAlias for dynamic cryptocurrency addresses in TXT records. You could register your address as bob@mycrypto.com and then use that address to receive a multitude of crypto by having a sender input  bob@mycrypto.com in a OpenAlias compliant wallet.

Comment: Ok, I know nothing about OpenAlias so just read a little about their TXT usage. Are those records really so much dynamic that you could not put them in a zonefile? nameservers allow dynamic updates if you like so you could have any program sending a specific "DNS update packet" with any new TXT value and the authoritative nameserver would replace it. With the appropriate security around it. May be easier/more secure/simpler than trying to have a NodeJS program responds dynamically to records. Except if they change like at each query or something.

Comment: This sounds like it could work. The records don't need to be super dynamic, but we still need to be able to change them when needed. In your solution we could be using an API our dns service has for registering a subdomain for each user as they register, right? I'll check what zonefiles and DNS update packets are to see if I could make use of that but it sounds like you're leading me in a better direction. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, either use some specific API or use standard DNS update packets if available (RFC2136) for which any DNS library could be used to generate them and send them to a nameserver accepting them (take care of standard security measures to authenticate the source in some way). This is the command line tool that does the same thing that could be useful to debug: https://linux.die.net/man/8/nsupdate

Answer (score 0):

As the discussion above suggests, you will need a way to programmatically set DNS subdomain.

Once you have the text records in place, your Node.js app can use [npm openalias to get cryptocurrency addresses](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openalias)